# OrientDB System Requirements

Tags: orientdb

What are the minimum reasonable memory and CPU requirements for OrientDB in a light-use production scenario with a relatively small database? I realize that "the more the better" is probably the answer, but I'm really just looking for a starting point based on anyone's real-world experience (i.e. "less than X just isn't workable").

Comment: If you use a small database the automatic settings ( heap 512m) should be reasonable. Orient has two types of memory: heap and disk-cache. If the heap is too low you risks the memory overflow because you have less memory than what you need. The heap memory is necessary. The disk-cache is used for the performances, higher is the memory and more higher are the performances, if you don't have enough disk-cache, the performances descrease. The disk-cache must be at most as large as the database.

Comment: @Alessandro: So for a small database with light load, running on a Linux server (dedicated to ODB) with 1GB of physical memory should be fine?

Comment: In your case, how many vertices do you think you will have and how many edges?

Comment: Probably well under 10K vertices with less than 4K record size and maybe 100K edges (mostly lightweight).

Comment: I think that 1GB of physical memory should be fine for you

Comment: By default, OrientDB version 3.0.x uses 2GB for heap in server.sh (standalone mode) and 4GB in dserver.sh (clustered mode), so I guess this is their recommended values.