# What are memory requirments for OrientDB/Can I run on EC2 micro?

Tags: memory, amazon-ec2, orientdb

I would like to run OrientDB on an EC2 micro (free tier) instance. I am unable to find official documentation for OrientDB that gives memory requirements, however I [found this question that says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038403/orientdb-system-requirements) 512MB should be fine. I am running an EC2 micro instance which has 1GB RAM. However, when I try to run OrientDB I get the JRE error shown below. My initial thought was that I needed to increase the jre memory using -xmx, but I guess it would be the shell script that would do this.. Has anyone successfully run OrientDB in an EC2 micro instance or run into this problem?

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007a04a0000, 1431699456, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1431699456 bytes for committing reserved memory.
 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /tmp/jvm-14728/hs_error.log
```

Here are the contents of the error log:

```
OS:Linux
uname:Linux 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 6 18:49:01 UTC 2018 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 3867, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:0.00 0.00 0.00

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1011168 kB
MemFree:          322852 kB
MemAvailable:     822144 kB
Buffers:           83188 kB
Cached:           523056 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           254680 kB
Inactive:         369952 kB
Active(anon):      18404 kB
Inactive(anon):       48 kB
Active(file):     236276 kB
Inactive(file):   369904 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                36 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         18376 kB
Mapped:            31660 kB
Shmem:                56 kB
Slab:              51040 kB
SReclaimable:      41600 kB
SUnreclaim:         9440 kB
KernelStack:        1564 kB
PageTables:         2592 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      505584 kB
Committed_AS:     834340 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       49152 kB
DirectMap2M:      999424 kB


CPU:total 1 (initial active 1) (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 63 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, erms, tsc

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x3c
cpu MHz     : 2400.043
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips    : 4800.05
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 1011168k(322728k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.181-b00) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_181-b00), built on Jun  5 2018 20:36:03 by "mockbuild" with gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)

time: Mon Aug 20 20:51:08 2018
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orient can easily run in 512MB though your performance and throughput will not be as high.  In OrientDB 3.0.x you can use the environment variable `ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY` to set it.  On the command line I can, for example run:

```
cd $ORIENTDB_HOME/bin
export ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xmx512m"
./server.sh
```

(where `$ORIENTDB_HOME` is where you have OrientDB installed) and I'm running with 512MB of memory.

As an aside, if you look in `$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/server.sh` you'll see that there is even code to check if the server is running on a Raspberry Pi and those range from 256MB to 1GB so the `t2.micro` will run just fine.

Comment: Yes- just what I needed. Thanks!